# ES6 reduce method not returning desired output

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

This is the output (***Image 1***) if you will log `final` array from **Snippet 1**

What I'm trying to do is to reduce my array to something like the displayed array in ***Image 2***

I already tried using lodash `_.uniqBy()` [***Snippet 2***], but still the output that I am getting from logging `reduce` variable is still the output from ***Image 1***. How can I reduce my `final` array to the output in ***Image 2***?

[image]
***Image 1***

[image]

***Image 2***

```
const reduce = final.reduce((x, y) => {
  if (x.department !== y.department) {
    return x;
  }
})

console.log(final)
console.log(reduce);
```

***Snippet 1***

```
_.uniqBy(final, 'department')
```

***Snippet 2***

***UPDATE***

This is in TypeScript `.ts` not in `.js`.

Interface => `[{ department: string, professors: string[] }]`

*As for request*

This is where I am getting my data

```
[
    {
      department: 'Department of Mathematics - INTRAMUROS',
      professors: [
        'Sabino, Lilibeth D.',
        'Department Chair',
 .....
```

And this is my code before arriving from my `final` array

```
const recommend = [];
const final = [];

recommended.forEach((prof) => {
  const find = proffessorDetails.find((collection) => {
    return collection.professors.find((professor) => professor == prof);
  });
  recommend.push(find);
})

const find = recommend.map((collection) => {
  return {
    department: collection.department,
    prof: _.intersection(collection.professors, recommended)
  };
});
final.push(find);
```

Comment: You always return the accumulator in reduce functions

Comment: That is not how you use `reduce`.

Comment: I see, so what possible could be the best work around to reduce my final array to the output in Image 2?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @str Noted. btw do you have any idea how solve this?

Answer (score 3):

It's better if you use a `Map` for this:

```
type department = { department: string, professors: string[] };
let mUnique : Map<string, department> = new Map(final.map((obj: department) => <[string, department]>[obj.department, obj]));
let mUniqueArray = [...mUnique.values()]; //or Array.from(mUnique.values());
```

Comment: Hi there @MinusFor, i got some lint errors in passing the final.map in Map, the error says argument of type void[] is not assignable

Comment: You are using typescript?

Comment: @Vadamadafaka, well you need to add the right type annotations. If you have your type definitions for your object I could help you. Idk if typescript supports `Map` natively now. Best I could do is suggest `Map<string, Object>` but I'm sure you'd want something more specific.

Comment: the interface is something like this `[{ department: string, professors: string[] }]`

Comment: @Vadamadafaka, alright, I updated the answer, see if that fixes it.

Comment: Man the output is still the same in Image 1 haha, I think maybe this is because we're using Map in typescript, or Map is not fully supported in ts. btw thank you once again @MinusFour

Answer (score 2):

With `reduce`, you would always modify the same object, and return it. It’s always easier to provide a starting value (`{}` in this case). `{}` is your `obj` at all times. To assign unique values (`item`s), you assign them to `obj[item.department]`. Don’t forget to `return` `obj` at the end.

```
const reduce = Object.values(final.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.department] = item;
  return obj;
}, {}));
```

With [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) you retrieve just the values from the reduced object.

Comment: Hi there @Xufox I tried the snippet but the return value is still the output in Image 1

Comment: @Vadamadafaka This isn’t possible. Please update your question and paste your actual `final` array as plain text (not as image) and format it as code (`{}` button).

Comment: This expression isn't being assigned to anything, so you need to put it somewhere

Comment: @MinusFour Right, I didn’t include the `const reduce =` in my snippet.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before you need to provide accumulator as first arg to reduce callback. Check this link: [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/Reduce). Not sure if that is what you want, but this code will give you array with objects that have unique `department` field

```
final.reduce((res, item ) => {
    return res.find(({ departament }) => departament === item.departament) ? res : [res, item];
}, [])
```